# Trying to loop through two arrays and format their output properly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to javascript and I am learning about looping through arrays. Anyways I have an array of prices and an array of names. I want the the output to be: "Name:Price". So for example:
Pound: 454
Half Pound: 227
Quarter Pound: 114
etc....

For some reason however the output that I am getting is a repeat of each name with each price next to it as you can see in the snippet below. Thanks for the help in advance. :)

```js
const salePrices = [454,227,114,28,14,7,3.5];

const names = ['Pound','Half-Pound','Quarter Pound','Ounce','Half Ounce','Quarter Ounce','Eighth'];

for (let i = 0; i < salePrices.length; i++){
  for(let x = 0; x < names.length; i++){
    console.log(`${names[x]}:${salePrices[i]}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: There is an infinite loop that you are creating because you are not incrementing the value of `x` in the inner loop. You don't need two loops for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need two loop for that. One loop would be enough to get the `index` and then get the `names` and `salePrices` from it as:

```js
const salePrices = [454, 227, 114, 28, 14, 7, 3.5];

const names = [
  "Pound",
  "Half-Pound",
  "Quarter Pound",
  "Ounce",
  "Half Ounce",
  "Quarter Ounce",
  "Eighth",
];

for (let i = 0; i < salePrices.length; i++) {
  console.log(`${names[i]}: ${salePrices[i]}`);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's because inner loop is running completely per one iteration of outer loop.
So for every **sales price**, **names** are running full.

If both arrays are already in correct order, you can just use one **for** loop.

```js
const salePrices = [454, 227, 114, 28, 14, 7, 3.5];

const names = [
  "Pound",
  "Half-Pound",
  "Quarter Pound",
  "Ounce",
  "Half Ounce",
  "Quarter Ounce",
  "Eighth",
];

for (var i = 0; i < salePrices.length; i++) {
  console.log(names[i] + ":" + salePrices[i])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you meant to increment `x` in the for loop instead of `i`.

In the first for loop you were iterating through the `salePrices`. Therefore `salePrices[i]` will get you `454 -> 227 -> 114 -> 28 -> 14 -> 7 -> 3.5`
In the second for loop you were iterating through the `names`. Therefore `names[x]` will get you `'Pound' -> 'Half-Pound' -> 'Quarter Pound' -> 'Ounce' -> 'Half Ounce' -> 'Quarter Ounce' -> 'Eighth'`

However, the second for loop is nested inside the first for loop. Therefore, all the `names` were iterated for each sales prices. Ex: 
When `i=0`, it will print:

```
Pound:454
Half-Pound:454
Quarter Pound:454
etc...
```

If you were sure the length of `names` and `salePrices` are the same. You can use [decpk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70431331/7099900).

You can also make them an object instead with `names` as key and `salePrices` as value (which is probably more fitting in this use case).

```js
const products = {
  "Pound": 454,
  "Half-Pound": 227,
  "Quarter Pound": 114,
  "Ounce": 28,
  "Half Ounce": 14,
  "Quarter Ounce": 7,
  "Eighth": 3.5,
};

for (const [name, price] of Object.entries(products)) {
  console.log(`${name}: ${price}`);
}
```